# PlayerJoinEvent isn't working correctly - Minecraft

Tags: java, minecraft

I created a config file for my plugin and I'm trying to get the PlayerJoinEvent to work so that when they join they will be displayed the message that is set in the config. When they join, no message is displayed though.
Code:

```
@EventHandler
public void onPlayerJoin(PlayerJoinEvent e) {
    Player p = e.getPlayer();

    String welcomeMessage = ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', 
            plugin.getConfig().getString("Message"));

    p.sendMessage(welcomeMessage);
}
```

Config:

```
Message: '&4did it work?'
```

And this part isn't as neccessary but incase you are wondering I have added this portion of the code for the config

```
private void registerConfig() {
    getConfig().options().copyDefaults(true);
    saveConfig();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you register your EventHandler on the PluginManager?
You can achieve this by placing the following code in your plugins  `onEnable()` method:

```
getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvent(new MyPlayerJoinListener(), this);
```

Hope it helps!